# Algorithm to generate Diagonal Latin Square matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I need for given N create N*N matrix which does not have repetitions in rows, cells, minor and major diagonals and values are 1, 2 , 3, ...., N.

For N = 4 one of matrices is the following:

```
 1 2 3 4 
 3 4 1 2 
 4 3 2 1
 2 1 4 3
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean exactly by 'main and major diagonals'.

Comment: in my example major diagonal is 1, 4,2,3 and minor  diagonal is 4, 1, 3, 2

Comment: Please tell us how you tried to solve this task?

Comment: I just did it for N = 4 by intuition, without using any algorithm.

Comment: no, I think it is not a magic square, it is more like sudoku, but it's not exactly sudoku too

Comment: Why do you use the definite article "the" in "the matrix is the following"? Are they known to be unique? Are they known to always exist? You are looking for a special type of Latin square, but with the addition of two more constraints. Surely somewhere in the literature on Latin squares there is discussion of the diagonals. As far as algorithms go -- an evolutionary approach might work.

Comment: I dont know if there is only one matrix for given N, but I thing that  the number of matrixes can be more than 1 or they can dont exist

Comment: @do you have limits for `N`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem overview**

The math structure you described is ***Diagonal Latin Square***. Constructing them is the more mathematical problem than the algorithmic or programmatic.

To correctly understand what it is and how to create you should read following articles:

1. [Latin squares definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_square)
2. [Magic squares definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)
3. [**Diagonal Latin square construction**](http://math.ucsb.edu/~padraic/mathcamp_2012/latin_squares/MC2012_LatinSquares_lecture5.pdf) <-- p.2 is answer to your question with proof and with other interesting properties

**Short answer**

One of the possible ways to construct ***Diagonal Latin Square***:

Let **N** is the power of required matrix **L**.

**If** there are exist numbers **A** and **B** from range `[0; N-1]` which satisfy properties:

- **A** relativly prime to **N**
- **B** relatively prime to **N**
- **(A + B)** relatively prime to **N**
- **(A - B)** relatively prime to **N**

**Then** you can create required matrix with the following rule:

```
L[i][j] = (A * i + B * j) mod N
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method which is fast for `N <= 9` : (python)

```
import random


def generate(n):
    a = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]

    def rec(i, j):
        if i == n - 1 and j == n:
            return True
        if j == n:
            return rec(i + 1, 0)
        candidate = set(range(1, n + 1))
        for k in range(i):
            candidate.discard(a[k][j])
        for k in range(j):
            candidate.discard(a[i][k])
        if i == j:
            for k in range(i):
                candidate.discard(a[k][k])
        if i + j == n - 1:
            for k in range(i):
                candidate.discard(a[k][n - 1 - k])
        candidate_list = list(candidate)
        random.shuffle(candidate_list)
        for e in candidate_list:
            a[i][j] = e
            if rec(i, j + 1):
                return True
            a[i][j] = 0
        return False

    rec(0, 0)
    return a


for row in generate(9):
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
[8, 5, 4, 7, 1, 6, 2, 9, 3]
[2, 7, 5, 8, 4, 1, 3, 6, 9]
[9, 1, 2, 3, 6, 4, 8, 7, 5]
[3, 9, 7, 6, 2, 5, 1, 4, 8]
[5, 8, 3, 1, 9, 7, 6, 2, 4]
[4, 6, 9, 2, 8, 3, 5, 1, 7]
[6, 3, 1, 5, 7, 9, 4, 8, 2]
[1, 4, 8, 9, 3, 2, 7, 5, 6]
[7, 2, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9, 3, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be nice to do this mathematically, but I'll propose the simplest algorithm that I can think of - brute force.

At a high level

- we can represent a matrix as an array of arrays
- for a given N, construct `S` a set of arrays, which contains every combination of `[1..N]`. There will be `N!` of these.
- using an recursive & iterative selection process (e.g. a search tree), search through all orders of these arrays until one of the 'uniqueness' rules is broken

For example, in your `N = 4` problem, I'd construct

```
S = [
[1,2,3,4], [1,2,4,3]
[1,3,2,4], [1,3,4,2]
[1,4,2,3], [1,4,3,2]
[2,1,3,4], [2,1,4,3]
[2,3,1,4], [2,3,4,1]
[2,4,1,3], [2,4,3,1]
[3,1,2,4], [3,1,4,2]
// etc
]

R = new int[4][4]
```

Then the algorithm is something like

1. If R is 'full', you're done
2. Evaluate does the next row from S fit into R,

   - if yes, insert it into R, reset the iterator on S, and go to 1.
   - if no, increment the iterator on S
3. If there are more rows to check in S, go to 2.

   - Else you've iterated across S and none of the rows fit, so remove the most recent row added to R and go to 1. In other words, explore another branch.

To improve the efficiency of this algorithm, implement a better data structure. Rather than a flat array of all combinations, use a prefix tree / Trie of some sort to both reduce the storage size of the 'options' and reduce the search area within each iteration.